# What is the concept behind LinearOperator in Scipy?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, linear-algebra

I have done some programming using LinearOperator from Scipy to perform linear algebra routines on large-scale matrices. However, I don't really understand the basic concept behind it. Is it related to the way how the data is loaded or partitioned?

Could someone explain to me the mechanism behind LinearOperators?

Comment: What about the docs? `Common interface for performing matrix vector products  Many iterative methods (e.g. cg, gmres) do not need to know the individual entries of a matrix to solve a linear system A*x=b. Such solvers only require the computation of matrix vector products, A*v where v is a dense vector. This class serves as an abstract interface between iterative solvers and matrix-like objects.`. See also: [Wiki: Matrix-free methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix-free_methods)

Comment: I am still not getting the exact mechanism. what does the compiler do?

Comment: I haven't dug in into the `scipy` solvers, but my impression is that they are iterative ones.   They don't 'compile' anything.  They don't do a full `A\b` matrix "divide/inverse" or `inv(A)`.  They don't invert `A` or otherwise manipulate or modify it.  Rather they repeatedly do a matrix-vector multiplication.  Hence all they need is that `A` can be used as the docs say - in a `A*v` expression.  There's lots of math theory about linear operators (even a wiki article or two).

Comment: Can you describe what you're doing with your LinearOperator -- solving Ax=b direct or iterative, or ... ? Then one could perhaps explain how the "mechanism" fits in the overall goal.

Comment: solving Ax=b using PCG